# Mount and Run an application programmatically in my Application

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, macos

Is there any one who knows how may I run an application package programmatically by giving file location path. Like if I want to install a software that needs Java for OS X. Then I might download the dmg file in background from url, save it and mount it. Then launch the .app or .pkg inside that DMG. I 'm looking any solution either in objective C or simple C/C++.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to install and run software without interaction and authorization from the user?

Comment: Yes. me asking exactly this.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not allowed by OS X. Doing so would permit malware to infect a user's computer.